# Angular-Google-Map: How to Load Map after Position Data Loaded(Lat, Lng)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I got the error:
'angular-google-maps: could not find a valid center property'. 
when I $watch my locationData loaded from php backend and exec initialize function.

HTML:

```
<div ng-init="locationData = '<?=htmlspecialchars($data)?>'">
    <google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options"></google-map>
</div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.$watch('locationData', function() {
        var location = JSON.parse($scope.locationData);
        $scope.location = {
            lng : location.longitude,
            lat : location.latitude
        initialize();
    });

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            panControl    : true,
            zoomControl   : true,
            scaleControl  : true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeId     : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        $scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: $scope.location.lat,
                longitude: $scope.location.lng
            },
            zoom: 13,
            options: mapOptions,
        };
    }
}]);
```

And, I move $scope.map settings to the top of the controller block and set constant value to map

```
center: {
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0
},
```

, map show correctly.

Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    'use strict';

    var mapOptions = {
        panControl    : true,
        zoomControl   : true,
        scaleControl  : true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeId     : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    $scope.map = {
        center: {
            latitude: 0,
            longitude: 0
        },
        zoom: 13,
        options: mapOptions,
    };
}]);
```

How can do google map directive parse after data loaded and show map correctly with backend Lat, Lng data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I use `ng-if`, and change `map.isReady` value from `false` to `true` after map initialize.

```
<div ng-init="locationData = '<?=htmlspecialchars($data)?>'">
    <div ng-if="map.isReady">
        <google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options"></google-map>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works.

Comment: +1. I used `ng-show` to hide the map until I was ready to display it and it messes up the canvas somehow. Changing this to `ng-if` works.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest alternative, [ng-map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps).

```
<map center="[<?=$data.latiude?>, <?=$data.longitude?>]" zoom="12" />
```

I created this directive, so it should work this way, and I believe this is the AngularJS way.

Answer (score 0):

`center` is set as:

```
        center: {
            latitude: $scope.location.lat,
            longitude: $scope.location.lng
        },
```

It should be like:

```
        center: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.location.lat, $scope.location.lng),
```

if lat/lng are numbers. If not that you have to use parseFloat().

Comment: Your center is value for google map api, not for Angular-google-map api.
Angular-google-map's center detail: Expression to evaluate as an object representing the map center. The object must have latitude and longitude numeric properties.